# javascript JSON.parse wrong timestamp

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, timestamp

"JSON.parse" parsing timestamp not correctly.

```
strObj='{"Timestamp":635450757182431418}';
console.log ('String object:'  + strObj ); //  Timestamp":635450757182431418
var parseObj= JSON.parse (strObj);
console.log (parseObj); // Timestamp: 635450757182431400
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwakwak/rqb6gf4z/

before parse: 635450757182431418,
after parse: 635450757182431400

What is the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`635450757182431418` is too big for the JavaScript format number, which is [IEEE754 double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), meaning there's about 53 bits for the integer part.

This number can't be exactly represented as a JavaScript number, you should use a different format (string, digit array, custom).

If you want to get the timestamp as a string, you might do this :

```
var strTimestamp = strObj.match(/"Timestamp"\s*:\s*(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Where does this string come from ? You should fix the problem at the source

Comment: Ajax - Its imposible to change the source, how can i parse as a string and not integer?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string `635450757182431418` value is stored, but as a number it's rounded to `635450757182431400`.

Just type this in chrome console

```
635450757182431418
```

You will get result as `635450757182431400` because Number doesn't support greater than `635450757182431400` in JS.